# how to access android app's certificate from inside the app?

Tags: android, certificate

Im trying to access the certificate/signature from inside an android app, so that I can do something with the certificate.
I googled a bit and found the code below:

```
Class c =  getClass();
ProtectionDomain pd = c.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cs = pd.getCodeSource();
Certificate[] signingCertificates = cs.getCertificates();
String st = signingCertificates[0].toString();
```

but `c.getProtectionDomain()` returns null.

anyone can help? many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Android sources:

```
frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PakcageParser.java
frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/Signature.java
```

You can perform the same on your app's own .apk.